# Turning rows with redundant information in columns

Tags: r

Please I have some data arranged in rows and I would like to organize these lines in columns using "R" as follows:

The idea is to get  "Allele, Effect and Obs" lines, which are arranged in 3 rows turning to columns. 
tag, Trait, Marker Locus are the same each three lines, what changes is the Allele, Effect and Obs.

Exemple:
Initial data

```
data1 <-"tag Trait Marker Locus Site Allele Effect Obs
ca-S10_17086845 ca S10_17086845 10 17086845 R 0.000001  54
ca-S10_17086845 ca S10_17086845 10 17086845 A 3.489820   1
ca-S10_17086845 ca S10_17086845 10 17086845 G -0.017141 389
cf-S10_9890328  cf S10_9890328 10 9890328 R 0.000001 146
cf-S10_9890328  cf S10_9890328 10 9890328 G 4.367540   1
cf-S10_9890328  cf S10_9890328 10 9890328 A -0.010635 297"
data1 <-read.table(text=data1,header=T)
```

Expected outcome

```
data2 <- "Trait Marker Allele Ef1 Ef2 Ef3 Obs1 Obs2 Obs3
ca S10_17086845 R/A/G 0.000001 3.489820 -0.017141 54 1 389
cf S10_9890328 R/G/A 0.000001 4.367540 -0.010635 146 1 297"
data2 <-read.table(text=data2,header=T)
```

Thank you

Comment: I am trying to follow all the stackoverflow rules so, kindly, I would like to know why It was drawn me a point, so I can improve the next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, where we first remove two irrelevant columns `tag` and `Site` which I think you should have done before posting to make the idea more clear; then summarize by `Trait`, `Marker` and `Locus` groups paste the `Allele` and `Effect` and `Obs` together. Finally a separation on columns `Effect` and `Obs` get to the result data frame:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
data1 %>% select(-tag, -Site) %>% group_by(Trait, Marker, Locus) %>% 
          summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse = "/"))) %>% 
          separate(Effect, into = paste("Eff", 1:3, sep = ""), sep = "/") %>% 
          separate(Obs, into = paste("Obs", 1:3, sep = ""), sep = "/")

# Source: local data frame [2 x 10]
# Groups: Trait, Marker [2]
# 
#    Trait       Marker Locus Allele     Eff1    Eff2      Eff3  Obs1  Obs2  Obs3
#   (fctr)       (fctr) (int)  (chr)    (chr)   (chr)     (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1     ca S10_17086845    10  R/A/G 0.000001 3.48982 -0.017141    54     1   389
# 2     cf  S10_9890328    10  R/G/A 0.000001 4.36754 -0.010635   146     1   297
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to paste alleles and also get first, second and third Effects or Obs.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% group_by(Trait, Marker) %>% summarize( allele = paste(Allele, collapse="/"), ef1=first(Effect), ef2=nth(Effect,2) , ef3=nth(Effect,3) )

  Trait       Marker allele      ef1     ef2       ef3
1    ca S10_17086845  R/A/G 0.000001 3.48982 -0.017141
2    cf  S10_9890328  R/G/A 0.000001 4.36754 -0.010635
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way, but this combo of dplyr and tidyr works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data3 <- data1 %>% 
          group_by(tag) %>% 
          mutate(obstag = paste0("Obs", seq_along(Obs)),  # Add markers
                 eftag = paste0("Ef", seq_along(Effect)),
                 altag = paste0("A", seq_along(Allele))) %>%
          spread(altag, Allele) %>%  # Switch from rows to columns 
          spread(obstag, Obs) %>% 
          spread(eftag, Effect) %>% 
          summarise_each(funs(unique(na.omit(.))), 1:Ef3) %>%  # Collapse into one row per tag 
          mutate(Allele = paste(A1, A2, A3, sep = "/")) %>% # paste alleles together
          select(-A1, -A2, -A3, -tag) # drop unwanted columns
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data1)`), create the 'Allele1' column by `paste`ing 'Allele' together after grouping by 'Trait' and 'Marker'.  Then, use `dcast` to reshape it to 'wide' format.  The `data.table::dcast` is different from the `reshape2:dcast` as it can also take multiple `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
setDT(data1)[,  Allele1 := paste(Allele, collapse="/") , .(Trait, Marker)]
dcast(data1, Trait + Marker + Allele1 ~ rowid(Trait), 
                              value.var = c("Effect", "Obs"))
#   Trait       Marker Allele1 Effect_1 Effect_2  Effect_3 Obs_1 Obs_2 Obs_3
#1:    ca S10_17086845   R/A/G 0.000001  3.48982 -0.017141    54     1   389
#2:    cf  S10_9890328   R/G/A 0.000001  4.36754 -0.010635   146     1   297
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this command is a little bit heavy to my data...
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11282.6 Gb